# return html tags in the html text using re

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x

I have html text and i just want to determine what are the html tags available in the text.

```
html_text = '<p class="gmail-m3464245979397595798gmail-m6143070745855285966gmail-m-3072962113628903492gmail-m-7999079541169053160wordsection1" style="margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt">Position Title: Onsite Client Services Associate<br /> Duration: 7 months<br /> Location: Tempe, AZ 85282<br /> &nbsp;<br /> <b><u>Roles and responsibilities</u></b><o:p></o:p></p> <p class="gmail-m3464245979397595798gmail-m6143070745855285966gmail-m-3072962113628903492gmail-m-7999079541169053160wordsection1" style="margin-top:5.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:.25in; margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span style="font-family:Symbol">&middot;</span><span style="font-size:7.0pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Primary function during peak season (July-December) will be an onsite presence at our large client in the Phoenix area. <o:p></o:p></p>'
```

As a first step I was parsing every tag from the text for every html tag
like `html_text.find('</p>')`. As it is very long to parse by checking with every tag, I was trying to use of regex

```
re.findall(r'\<\/.>', html_text)
```

The output of the above is `['</p>', '</b>', '</u>']`. But I want the output to be `['</p>','</span>', '<br />', '</b>', '</u>']`. So If I modify

```
re.findall(r'\<\/.*>', html_text)
```

presuming i can get `</span>`, I am getting the whole text.

```
['</u></b><o:p></o:p></p> <p class="gmail-m3464245979397595798gmail-m6143070745855285966gmail-m-3072962113628903492gmail-m-7999079541169053160wordsection1" style="margin-top:5.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:.25in; margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span style="font-family:Symbol">&middot;</span><span style="font-size:7.0pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Primary function during peak season (July-December) will be an onsite presence at our large client in the Phoenix area. <o:p></o:p></p>']
```

Is there a way I can write the expression for all tags as one expression or else should I write condition check for every tag ? In the above I couldn't determine `<br />`.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'</?(\w+)[^>]*>', html_text)`

Comment: thank you for awesome answer @WiktorStribiżew, what is that w+ doing for the expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some little trails, I have found answer for my self, just posting it if it would help some one. It will determine all the tags, do some cleaning will determine the tags.

```
re.findall(re.compile("<.*?>"), html_text)
```

output is

```
['<p class="gmail-m3464245979397595798gmail-m6143070745855285966gmail-m-3072962113628903492gmail-m-7999079541169053160wordsection1" style="margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt">', '<br />', '<br />', '<br />', '<br />', '<b>', '<u>', '</u>', '</b>', '<o:p>', '</o:p>', '</p>', '<p class="gmail-m3464245979397595798gmail-m6143070745855285966gmail-m-3072962113628903492gmail-m-7999079541169053160wordsection1" style="margin-top:5.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:.25in; margin-bottom:.0001pt">', '<span style="font-family:Symbol">', '</span>', '<span style="font-size:7.0pt">', '</span>', '<o:p>', '</o:p>', '</p>']
```

Comment: for negative marking let me know why it is marked negative.

Comment: Your solution doesn't match what you mentioned in the question. You wanted to match only ['<p>','<span>', '<br />', '<b>', '<u>'].

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, what you are trying to do won't be fully achievable with just regex.

Usually, in an HTML tag there are attributes inside the opening tag. For example-
`<span class="text">Some Text </span>` has `class="text"` between the opening `<span` and the closing `>`.

So, if you want to just match `<span>` from `<span class="text">Some Text </span>`, you'll have to match `<span` first and then somehow skip `class="text"` and match `>` again. Which is not possible with regex as regex can only match characters one after another.

---

One solution that comes to my mind is, you can use this regex `(<[^\/\s]+)([^>]+)>`. Which will match `<span class="text">Some Text </span>` and return `<span`. You can then just add `>` after that using string concatenation.

Regex Explanation-

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: answer is possible with regex, i posted answer, just have a look.

Comment: @Raady No, you mentioned in the question that you want to match only ['<p>','<span>', '<br />', '<b>', '<u>']. However your regex will match everything between `<p` to `>`. How's that similar?

Comment: once you have found out all the tags, it is easy to determine req_tags by ignoring </"req_tag">

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question, did you? I know that's easy. But you have to be clear about what you are looking for.